# ASPX has image from portal.mxlogic.com

Tags: image, asp.net

I have a aspx page I'm trying to (remotely) debug.  It should add an image and set the src.  The value seems correct if i msgbox the value that should be used for the "ImageUrl"

But viewing the page there is no image and the src is:

http://portal.mxlogic.com/images/transparent.gif

This is a mcaffee page so is this some security thing...that is just a wild\crazy guess.  Maybe i'm missing something very obvious...I did not write the code and I'm not really a aspx developer.

Any ideas??

llf

as requested some code...

```
TableCell tc = new TableCell();

{code to create imgurl ... very specific to this situation}

MessageBox(imgurl);  //The imgurl value here is correct
if (imgurl != null)
{    
  image.ImageUrl = imgurl;
}
else
{
   MessageBox("image url is null"); 
}

tc.Controls.Add(image);
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
Table1.Rows.Add(tr)
```

Comment: Some code would be nice.

Comment: See this related question: [Using an HTTP handler in ASP.NET to generate an image for display in email][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692634/using-an-http-handler-in-asp-net-to-generate-an-image-for-display-in-email/11759655#11759655

Answer (score 0):

http://portal.mxlogic.com/images/transparent.gif points to a transparant image of 1 by 1 pixel.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the url was pointing to an older server.  Once that was corrected the images I expected were displayed.  How "http://portal.mxlogic.com/images/transparent.gif" was getting substituted I still don't understand.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This might shed some light on the issue: http://www.myicontrol.com/fusetalk/messageview.cfm?catid=28&threadid=793

It seems like there is something replacing images in emails with the image you found.

Comment: On Stackoverflow we like to include some of the code from the link, that way if/when the link dies then we still have a good answer. Please leave the link in place as it may be helpful to someone else.